# get_posts shows current post, not defined posts with args

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I want to show defined posts but get_posts shows current post without use definition in args.Why, how to solve it? what is difference between get_posts and wp query? thanks

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_shop' );
function check_shop()
{
    if (is_shop() ) {
            $args1 = array(
                'post_author' => 'admin',
                'post_type' => 'page',
            );
            $post_types1 = get_posts( $args1, 'objects' );
            foreach ($post_types1 as $post_type1) {
                setup_postdata( $post_type1 );
                if (!empty($post_type1->post_content)) {
                    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
                        global $post_type1;
                        the_title();
                        echo get_the_title($post_type1->ID);
                        echo $post_type1;
                        echo $post_type1->post_content;
                        echo "denemeee yazısı";
                    }, 1);
                }
            }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/):

> `setup_postdata()` does **not** assign the global `$post` variable so it’s
> important that you do this yourself. Failure to do so will cause
> problems with any hooks that use any of the above globals in
> conjunction with the `$post` global, as they will refer to separate
> entities.

So you need to do this:

```
global $post; // This...

foreach ($post_types1 as $post_type1) {
    $post = $post_type1; // ...and this.

    setup_postdata( $post_type1 );

    // etc.
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I didnt understand your fast answer.i couldnt work your code.can you edit your answer with true form of my code, it will be more helper for me

Comment: It is your code, I just added two lines, which I indicated. Just place them in the same place.

Comment: in old times, you helped me but this answer is not one of them.if I have more reputation, I  can give thumb down.because your code doesn't work or I couldn't work it.Can you prepare good answer instead of fast answer?

Comment: What kind of moderator are you? if you know the answer, do good reply, if you don't know, why you take my time? delete it or change it